# Object Mapping without losing existing data

Tags: java, oop, modelmapper

Usually Object Mappers are for scenarios to map a larger set of data to small set (example: `Entity` object has a lot of data but we want to return only a few of them).

Object mappers usually create a new Instance of destination object of small set and set the required fields from source object with larger set, but I have opposite scenario: I have a destination object which already contains some data and now I need to map a new source object with smaller data set into destination object.

Source Class

```
public class SrcObj {
private String name;
private int i;
```

Destination Class

```
public class DestObj {
    private String name;
    private int i;
    private float f;
    private boolean b;
```

DesObj already contains the value of int i and float f, SrcObj has  String name and int, i need to save SrcObj data into DestObj without losing existing data.

Model Mapper always creating a new Object of DestObj which will map SrcObj into it but rest of the fields are null.

```
public class ObjectMapper {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    SrcObj src = new SrcObj("src name", 1);
    DestObj dest = new DestObj(null, 0, 1, true);
ModelMapper modelMapper = ObjectMapper.modelMapper();
    dest = modelMapper.map(src, DestObj.class);
    System.out.println(dest);
}

private static ModelMapper modelMapper() {
    ModelMapper modelMapper = new ModelMapper();
    PropertyMap<SrcObj, DestObj> orderMap = new PropertyMap<SrcObj, DestObj>() {
        protected void configure() {
            // map().setI(destination.getI());
            map().setI(source.getI());
            System.out.println("model mapper");
            map().setName(source.getName());
        }
    };

    modelMapper.addMappings(orderMap);
    return modelMapper;
}
}
```

there is an option in Model mapper to use destination, commented above but it's not working.

how can i have destObj containing all values
destObj[name="src name", i=1,f=1.1,b=true]

Comment: You forgot to ask a question....

Comment: http://modelmapper.org/javadoc/org/modelmapper/ModelMapper.html#map-java.lang.Object-java.lang.Object-. But in my experience, such mappers should be avoided at all cost: they only save you a few lines of trivial code to copy properties from one object to another, but make things a lot harder when dealing with more complex mappings, imutable objects, etc. And most importantly, they fail silently when you rename a property in the source class and don't apply the same refactoring on the destination class (or vice-versa), leading to plenty of bugs that don' happen if you code the copy by yourself.

Comment: @JBNizet I already went through the documentation but didn't succeed.

yes, I know the implications but right now I have simple objects so it doesn't matter.

Comment: Then post a complete minimal example of what you tried after using the method I linked to, and tell precisely what you expected to happen, and what happened instead.

Comment: HI @JBNizet I hope this is what you are saying 

`modelMapper.map(src, dest);`

but its giving compile time error Type mismatch: cannot convert from void to DestObj because this overloaded method return type is void.

Comment: Just **read** the error message. This method returns void. You can't assign its result to `dest`. And there is no reason to, since this method does't create a new DestObj: it modifies `dest`. Just like you can't use `dest = dest.setName("foo");`. You just use `dest.setName("foo");`.

Comment: I don't want to use getters or setters, that's the whole point of using Object Mapper, it seems only 1 getter and setter in this example but in my project, it's around 10-15.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@Chun Han Hsiao thanks for your response, it worked, just for the sake of solution.

```
    SrcObj src = new SrcObj("src name", 1);
        DestObj dest = new DestObj(null, 0, 1, true);
    ModelMapper modelMapper = ObjectMapper.modelMapper();
 modelMapper.map(src, dest);
        System.out.println(dest);
```

Answer (score 0):

First, if you don't want to use getter/setter in your classes, you can just enable the field matching feature.

```
modelMapper.getConfiguration()
    .setFieldMatchingEnabled(true)
    .setFieldAccessLevel(AccessLevel.PRIVATE);
```

And you can simply `modelMapper.map(src, dest)` that will update the dest's properties from source.